# How do I create a transparent 'hotspot' with XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am entirely new to coding (as in just learning over the past month), so bear with me if this is an obnoxiously simple question to ask. I am writing a Windows 8 app using XAML/C#. I would like to create transparent buttons on the page that are actionable. The idea, in case you're wondering, is that a small child will be able to accidentally discover an action by just playing around. I don't want any visual clues that the 'hotspot' exists. I have created buttons that are transparent. However, when the page loads, the button show, temporarily, as grey and then change to transparent. I've done a fair share of researching this, but no luck. I'm thinking that it is such an obvious and simple answer that no one has bothered to ask it :) Any suggestions would be so welcome! Thanks!

```
 <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid x:Name="LandingPage1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}">
            <Run Text="talk to "/>
            <Run Foreground="#FF0770A2" Text="me"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="526" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="607" Margin="73,31,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
        <Image Height="382" Source="Assets/TTMBabyCrying.jpg" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="38,0,10,0"/>
        <Image x:Name="btnNeedPageNav" Height="150" Source="Assets/TMMneed.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" PointerPressed="btnNeedPageNav_PointerPressed"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Height="526" Margin="715,31,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Width="607" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Height="379" Margin="0" Source="Assets/TTMBoyBall.jpg" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="474" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Image x:Name="btnWantPageNav" Height="150" Margin="0" Source="Assets/TTMwant.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="320" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" PointerPressed="btnWantPageNav_PointerPressed"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="btnBabyCrying" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,127,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="116" Width="121" PointerPressed="btnBabyCrying_PointerPressed" Click="btnBabyCrying_Click" DragOver="btnBabyCrying_DragOver" Holding="btnBabyCrying_Holding" Opacity="0.0"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnNeedPageNav1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,261,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="357" Width="650" ClickMode="Press" Click="btnNeedPageNav1_Click" Opacity="0"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnWantPageNav1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="715,410,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="208" Width="641" Opacity="0.0"/>
    <Ellipse x:Name="BlueBall" Fill="#FF5AA2D8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Stroke="#FF5AA2D8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Margin="878,261,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="0.7" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" PointerPressed="BlueBall_PointerPressed">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the button dynamically in code? I'm not 100% sure how to do that, but it's an option. Alternatively, load them in first with "visible=false" then in code change visible to true.

Comment: You need to change the control template of button. use expression blend and edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a neat project. There's multiple ways of doing this. My suggestion would be to take a default Button Style Template and butcher it to fit your needs then call it to the instance, so something like this (Keep in mind I left a lot of extra clutter in here for reference or if you wanted to add anything to it.) Notice your setters, and I set the ContentPresenter to Visibility="Collapsed"

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform />
                                <SkewTransform />
                                <RotateTransform />
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <!-- In case you need it later -->
                        <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

You can place this template in your Resource Dictionary, or your Object.Resources etc. Then just call it for the instances you need in your views like;

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentButtonStyle}" Height="50" Width="50"/>
```

Hope this helps, let us know if you need anything explained, and have fun! :)

Comment: Thanks Chris! Would this be a technique used if I were employing MVVM? I'm trying to learn good habits from the start, but not sure where to even start :)

Comment: Well I suppose it depends on what you're referring to by technique? You'll likely run into a lot of instances where you'll need to edit/customize a control style template, not so much MVVM dependent.